# Can't update R or install R-studio in conda R environment

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, conda

I had previously installed conda on Linux Ubuntu.
Then I created R environment with this tutorial:

'Install R in a separate environment. Conda packages requiring my downgrade or upgrade your r-base which might cause version problems. Use conda create -n R to create new environment.
Always install r-essentials package rather than conventional r-base to prevent yourself from the horrors curl, curl, zlib, glib brings with them in r-base. conda install -c r r-essentials '

It worked OK, I installed a jupyter lab also and used R in jupyter lab for some time.
But then i tried to update R and got problems, and when i tried to install R-studio i got the same looking problems. The log is below.

```
conda install -c r rstudio
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
```

And then this 'Solving environment' hangs forever with no result

Comment: Generally, I do not recommend to use the `r` channel as it stopped being maintained (though recently it seems Anaconda has started rebuilding some of the packages). Instead, the `conda-forge` channel is the most well-supported collection of R packages. Try using that instead. Note that RStudio ships under the package name `rstudio-desktop` on Conda Forge.